# I want a blurred background image with overlay text

Tags: html, css, background-image, blur

So, I am taking the jumbotron out of the container because I want it to be full width. But when I apply text to the jumbotron it blurs it out as well. I tried doing the opposite and throwing my background image in a separate `<div>` but couldn't manage to make it take up the full space like I had it before. Thoughts?

[My codepen project...](http://codepen.io/mvadamski/pen/VKxAyd)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 40px;
    margin: -15px 0px 0px 0px;
    top: -25px; right: 30px;
}

.jumbotron {
  width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron {
  background:url("http://www.incimages.com/uploaded_files/image/1940x900/software-computer-code-1940x900_35196.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5.5px);
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand text-center">Michael Adamski <br><span class="sub-brand">- Web Developer -</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" id="navbar-list">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li a href="home" class="active">Home</li>
          <li a href="#about">About</li>
          <li a href="portfolio">Portfolio</li>
          <li a href="Contact">Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navigation Bar -->

   <!-- Header -->
<div class="jumbotron">
 <div class="container">
    <h1> This is my Page! </h1>
    <p> This is an example of what I can do with my newfound knowledge</p>
  
  

</body>
```

Comment: how exactly would I do that? Do i remove the background-image from the .jumbotron class or duplicate with blur effect on a pseudo element? Im super noviced to pseudo classes and stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a simple pseudo class - [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jessengatai/prshdcj4/3/)

The idea is to put the background into it's own pseudo element so the blur wont effect the children of the `.jumbotron` div. Pay particular attention to the z-index and position settings, as they place the background behind the content.

```
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.jumbotron:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;  
  background:url("http://example.com/linktoimage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: blur(5.5px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Also notice the `transform: scale(1.1);`, this will make the background slightly larger than the container so you don't get the 'white' fade out towards the edges. The wrapper `.jumbotron` then has `overflow: hidden;` to hide the image overflow.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to replace the jumbotron by a `div` inside of which you place your heading, paragraph, and an image:

```css
#bg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5.5px);
  max-width: 100%;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  width: 100%;
}

#header h1 {
  margin-top: 20%;
}

#header p {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

#header p, #header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1> This is my Page! </h1>
  <p> This is an example of what I can do with my newfound knowledge</p>
  <img id="bg" src="http://www.incimages.com/uploaded_files/image/1940x900/software-computer-code-1940x900_35196.jpg">
</div>
```

You may need to adjust the padding and margin for the navigation.